# Access oldPanel hidden HTML variable in jQuery-UI Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery-ui 1.9.0.  I have some tabs like these:

```
<li><a href="#document-tab" onclick="return documentTabGet('CRFilingDocument.do', null);">Documents</a></li>
<li><a href="#litigant-tab" onclick="return litigantTabGet('CRFilingLitigantDetail.do', null)">Litigants</a></li>
<li><a href="#scheduling-tab" onclick="return schedulingTabGet('CRFilingScheduling.do', null);">Scheduling</a></li>
```

I have setup a beforeActivate function

```
jQuery("#reviewtabs").tabs({ 
    select:
        function (event, ui) {
            return CheckSomething();
        },

    show: 
        function (event, ui) { 
            //do some stuff
        },
    beforeActivate: 
        function( event, ui ) {
        return CheckSomething();
    }

});
```

On the JSP that renders one of those tabs I would like to check a hidden HTML input in the beforeActivate.  In Chrome console I can see the HTML from typing ui.oldPanel, how get access to the hidden fields value?  I have tried ui.oldPanel.find("dirtyCheck").value and it comes back undefined.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: This is HTML <input type="hidden" name="dirtyCheck" id="dirtyCheck" value="false"/> This worked for me if(ui.oldPanel.find("input[name=dirtyCheck]").val()==="true") { Thanks  @яden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if `ui.oldPanel` is not undefined, we need to know what `dirtyCheck` is. Is it the input id ? the input css class ? or something else ?

If `dirtyCheck` is the id of the `<input id="dirtyCheck" type="hidden" value="..."/>` you are looking for, you can get its value using an [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method :

```
ui.oldPanel.find('#dirtyCheck').val();
```

If `dirtyCheck` is its css class, use a [css selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method :

```
ui.oldPanel.find('.dirtyCheck').val();
```

If the returned value is still undefined, double-check that your input is really in the `ui.oldPanel` :) and give us the html where the input is.